# Finding out if a column is hidden in an excel file using EPPLUS

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I have a project which reads in a excel file using EPPlus. However, often the files can include hidden columns.

Is there a way of determining if a column is hidden using EPPlus?

I basically want to ignore any hidden columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an `OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet ws` (from the EPPlus assembly)

```
var hidden = ws.Columns(1).Hidden;
```